# Fast search and replace regex

Tags: python, regex

Just trying to do fast search and replace for strings in Python using `re`

```
replacements = {r'\btest\b': 'Exam', r'\bhello\b': 'Hi', r'\bruby\b': 'Gem'}
replacements_pattern = '|'.join(replacements.keys())
text = 'this is a ruby Test, testing'
re.sub(replacements_pattern, lambda match: replacements[match.group()], text, re.IGNORECASE)

text
>> 'this is a Gem Exam, testing'
```

The issue with this, is that the `match.group()` will give back 'test', and thus not be able to match to the key `r'\btest\b'`, so how can I handle this?

Edit: You can extract the breakpoints, st:

```
replacements = {r'test': 'Exam', r'hello': 'Hi', r'ruby': 'Gem'}
replacements_pattern = r'(?i)\b(?:' + '|'.join(replacements) + r')\b'
replacements_pattern = re.compile(replacements_pattern)
text = 'this is a ruby Test, testing'
re.sub(replacements_pattern, lambda match: replacements[match.group().lower()], text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Thanks for the advise so far!

Question remaining: The key retrieved in match.group() may not match keys in the dictionary, thus causing a match error!

Comment: You don't need word boundaries around your keys. Also you don't need to use `dict.keys()` to join them. You can simply do `'|'.join(replacements)`

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Kasramvd. I do need boundaries, else I'll match on words incorporated in others

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give `\b` in dict keys. Just change your pattern like below,

```
replacements = {r'test': 'Exam', r'hello': 'Hi', r'ruby': 'Gem'}
replacements_pattern = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(replacements) + r')\b'
```

to do a case-insensitive match,

```
replacements_pattern = r'(?i)\b(?:' + '|'.join(replacements) + r')\b'
```

Comment: This is a good tip wrt breakpoints. Issue with the case aspect is that it then wont find the key in replacements

Comment: yes this does work, but really only handling break point aspect. It doesn't consider what is returned from `match.group() ` in `re.sub(replacements_pattern, lambda match: replacements[match.group()], text, re.IGNORECASE` which would cause a key invalid error when matching to the dictionary